# JavaScript - How to set request header for a browser GET

Tags: javascript, rest, browser, http-headers, httprequest

If we do `window.location = "http://MyApi.com/Pdf";`, browser does a GET of the URL `http://MyApi.com/Pdf`. But if we want to set `authentication` header of the request before doing GET of the URL because the server is a REST server and it doesn't support cookies. How to do this?

In all of the cases, I'm using `$.ajax` to call service but this time I need to show the response in a new window. Response is a PDF file content.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In more recent browsers, you might be able to use blobs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="tryit();">PDF</button>
<script>
    function tryit() {
        var win = window.open('_blank');
        downloadFile('/pdf', function(blob) {
            var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            win.location = url;
        });
    }
    function downloadFile(url, success) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("username:password"));
        xhr.responseType = "blob";
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                if (success) success(xhr.response);
            }
        };
        xhr.send(null);
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In IE, ask the user:

```
window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, 'readme.pdf');
```

P.S.
You can test the backend in Node:

```
router.get('/pdf', function(req, res) {
  if(req.headers.authorization !== 'Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=') return res.status(403).send('Not allowed');
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'render.pdf'));
});
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index');
});
```

Comment: Yes, with Chrome 48 -> Node 0.12
Mark it up? :)

Comment: supported by major latest browsers. But still in draft. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for... Or correct me if i am wrong.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Setting_HTTP_request_headers

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about hiding or obfuscating the user credentials then just use plain GET authentification: 
use `http://username:password@MyApi.com/` instead of `http://MyApi.com/`

Comment: Thanks v much for replying. I have a custom authentication mechanism. :(. So the value of `authorization` header looks something like `CompanyNameToken <hashOfToken>`. I wouldn't mind including the token in the URL if there is some quirk possible like this one.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be a GET?

The reason I am asking is that you could just have a POST form (to a target="_BLANK") that posts whatever but shows an embedded file in a new window. Of course this wouldn't solve the  issue with your custom headers, but then since you can also POST using jquery.ajax - which does allow you to set your own headers - you'd have the best of both worlds.

Here's a [jQuery plugin](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_plugin_for_requesting_ajax_like_file_downloads/) that creates such a form dynamically in order to download whichever file. You could use this as a reference...

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You may consider setting the header in beforeunload or onunload event handler

Comment: Please provide some working code example to support your answer?

Answer (score -2):

You should configure `$.ajax` using `beforeSend`. Below an example, but of course I don't know if the exact setup will work for you without any code to look at.

```
$.ajax( {
    url : '/model/user.json',
    dataType : 'json',
    'beforeSend' : function(xhr) {
            var bytes = Crypto.charenc.Binary.stringToBytes(username + ":" + password);
            var base64 = Crypto.util.bytesToBase64(bytes);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64);
    },
    error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        reset();
        onError('Invalid username or password. Please try again.');
        $('#loginform #user_login').focus();
    },
    success : function(model) {
        cookies();
            ...
    }
});
```

For this to work you need [crypto-js](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/).

Comment: Doesn't quite answer the question I believe, the response is a PDF document to be rendered by the browser.

Comment: Let me clarify again. I don't need to set header for ajax request. I want to set header for full GET request of the page. I'm already using the `beforeSend` to set the header for all ajax request.